# Capybara not finding the same link twice using find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to write a test for an AJAX call. The functionality works in production, but I'm having trouble with Capybara. It seems `find(".selector").click` can't be called twice within the same scenario.

Scenario #1 passes, but scenario #2 gives this error on the second `find(".article__expand").click`:

```
Failure/Error: find(".article__expand").click
  Capybara::ElementNotFound:
    Unable to find css ".article__expand"
```

I'm using a CSS selector because the link's body is a glyphicon span. Is there a way around this?

---

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.feature "Users can toggle article descriptions" do
  let(:article) { FactoryGirl.create(:article, description: "Article description") }

  context "all users" do
    before do
      visit article_path(article)
    end

    scenario "description is hidden until clicked" do
      expect(page).to_not have_content("Article description")

      find(".article__expand").click

      expect(page).to have_content("Article description")
    end

    scenario "description can be toggled" do
      expect(page).to_not have_content("Article description")

      find(".article__expand").click

      expect(page).to have_content("Article description")

      find(".article__expand").click

      expect(page).to_not have_content("Article description")
    end
  end
end
```

Here's how the call is made. I'm using a custom `description` get member on `resources :articles`.

```
# views/articles/_article.html.erb
<div class="article" id="article-<%= article.id %>">
  <%= link_to description_article_path(article), remote: true, class: "article__expand" do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  <% end %>
  <div class="article__info">
  </div>
</div>

# views/articles/description.js.erb
$(function() {
  if ($("#article-<%= @article.id %> .article__description").length) {
    $("#article-<%= @article.id %> .article__description").toggle();
  } else {
    $.getJSON( '/articles/<%= @article.id %>.json', function( data ) {
      var description = ('<p class="article__description">' + data.description + '</p>')
      $('#article-<%= @article.id %> .article__info').prepend(description);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm only guessing here since I'm no CSS expert. But if  `.article_expand` is clicked, it would be expanded and the class should change to something like `.article_minimize`. Have you implemented any such functionality?

Comment: @bork No nothing like that, I'll edit in the views. They're pretty simple so I think this is a Capybara issue, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Which capybara driver are you using?

Comment: are you sure the ".article__expand" class doesn't change when clicking on it?

Comment: have you tried a `save_and_open_page` so you can look and see what it actually looks like (and what classes are present) before the second click?

Answer (score 0):

To debug these sort of things I would recommend the following steps:

`gem install launchy`

Launch says: Launchy is here to make a common approach to launching external application from within ruby programs.

Make use of `save_and_open_page` within your spec just before the expectation that is failing. Someting like the below:

```
scenario "description can be toggled" do
  expect(page).to_not have_content("Article description")
  find(".article__expand").click
  save_and_open_page
  expect(page).to have_content("Article description")
  find(".article__expand").click
  ....
```

This will make it alot easier to debug. Also consider taking a different approach and using the the Capybara methods such as:

```
=Clicking links and buttons=
    click_link('id-of-link')
    click_link('Link Text')
    click_button('Save')
    click('Link Text') # Click either a link or a button
    click('Button Value')
```

These come from a super helpful Capybara cheatsheet found here  - https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105

Comment: This brought more questions than answers unfortunately. I might do an update and try to get help debugging, but I have a feeling the issue due to my unconventional custom `description` get member.

Comment: Ah ok. Maybe you can also update with more details on your Capybara Driver? (Selenium, Capybara-Webkit or Poltergeist?) and that setup. I would say that is a likely area for an issue if you are still unsure why it's failing.

Comment: I'm using Capybara-Webkit, but basically with `:js => true` it's failing at the controller level. It can't find the instance's ID using `Model.find`. It doesn't make a whole lot of sense since FactoryGirl is making the instance, and it's lazy loaded etc. Confusing!